# Denseness in a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $A$ be a metric space. Suppose $C \subset B \subset  A$  and $C$ is dense in $A$.
Then is it true that $B$ is dense in $A$? 
My attempt: 
For given $\epsilon \geq 0$ and $ a \in A$, there exists $c \in C s.t. | a-c| \leq \epsilon$ but $c$ can be regarded as element of $B$ so we are done.

If above claim is true then can I use it to deduce that:
Space of smooth function with compact support is dense in $L_\mathbb C (\mathbb R) \cap L_\mathbb C ^2(\mathbb R) $ and $L_\mathbb C (\mathbb R)$ so $L_\mathbb C (\mathbb R) \cap L_\mathbb C ^2(\mathbb R) $ is dense in $L_\mathbb C (\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wour attempt, put “can be regarded as element of $B$” instead of “can be regarded as element of $C$” and you're done.

Comment: thanks!  I edited the post. It was a typo.

Comment: @HeeJuneKim If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Does the voting make it an accepted answer?

Comment: @HeeJuneKim No. Please click the ✓ symbol below the downvote arrow.